# closing showModalBottomSheet from showDialog flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

is it possible to close the showModalBottomSheet from a showDialog.

i have the bellow showmodalsheet that i want to close whenever i click on the showDialog

```
 GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
                        isScrollControlled: true,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        context: context,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(
                                  SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal! * 5.8),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(
                                  SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal! * 5.8)),
                        ),
                        // context: context,
                        builder: ((builder) => showModalOption()));
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.more_vert,
                    color: AppColor.blackColor,
                  ))


showModalOption(){
return Text("modal is opened")
```

i have the below showDialog that have a button close which i want to use to close the showModalSheet.

```
 showDialogBox(title, description, proceed) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal! * 5))),
            // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            content: GestureDectector(){
ontap:(){
 Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context);
},
child :Text("Close Modal")
```

but when i cliked onthe Close modal, only the dialog box closed . thank you all

Comment: pop it twice  `ontap:(){
 Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context); 
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context);
},`

Comment: Thanks @griffins, I will try it now

Comment: hi, @griffins i tried it, but it don't work